Render a grid column as LOV or text field
I have a interactive grid , which I want to render a column called TEST_COLUMN as LOV or text field based on a condition .
for example the condition  is on page load which for some records the column TEST_COLUMN should be an LOV and some others this column should be display as a text field .
Note : I don't want use manual entry here .
Is that possible to make this column like this ?

Don't think this is possible. A column has an item type. It can conditionally be made only but not conditionally have another type.
